# Query Help. Split row into 5 different rows

Tags: sql, split, row

I have a timequery that has the following.

```
ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd1, endd1, startt1, endt1, startd2, endd2, startt2, endt2, startd3, endd3, startt3, endt3, startd4, endd4, startt4, endt4, startd5, endd5, startt5, endt5
```

I need to split the row so it will show

```
ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd1, endd1, startt1, endt1
ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd2, endd2, startt2, endt2
ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd3, endd3, startt3, endt3
ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd4, endd4, startt4, endt4
ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd5, endd5, startt5, endt5
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The generic way in SQL is to use `union all`:

```
select ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd1 as startd, endd1 as endd, startt1 as startt, endt1 as endt
from t
union all
select ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd2, endd2, startt2, endt2
from t
union all
select ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd3, endd3, startt3, endt3
from t
union all
select ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd4, endd4, startt4, endt4
from t
union all
select ID, StaffName, PName, Description, startd5, endd5, startt5, endt5
from t;
```

If you have a large table, there are more efficient methods.  This requires scanning the table once for each subquery.

The column names come from the first subquery, which renames them so there are no numbers.